# Attack Power and Attack Roll

Tags: dnd-4e

Let's say I use an Attack Power that runs the Attack Roll on Strength vs AC (with the key word *Weapon*) which if hit then does `1 [W]+Strength Modifier`.

Since I also have proficiency with the weapon, do I then gain the Proficiency Value from the weapon to that roll or do I only gain that proficiency value on a Basic attack?

Answer (score 10):

You gain the proficiency bonus of the weapon as long as:

1. You are proficient with the weapon, and
2. The power has the Weapon keyword.

In your case, both are true so yes, you do!

Edit: Just for clarity, since it isn't entirely clear what you mean: Proficiency bonuses apply to attack rolls only, not damage rolls.

Comment: I see, Thank you very much.
(And yes, sry... it was unclear of me).

Comment: @Lucifer you should mark the answer as accepted since it appears to be exactly what you were looking for.