# Do weapon proficiencies affect ONLY basic attacks, or also martial attack powers?

Tags: dnd-4e

So in D&D 4e, let's say I want to play as a paladin. The paladin's weapon proficiencies are: "Simple melee, military melee, simple ranged".

So if I use, say, a longsword in order to perform a melee basic attack. It would mean that due to my proficiency with melee weapons, I would gain a +2 power bonus to my attack.

Now, let's say that instead, I want to use an attack power. So let's say, "Bolstering strike" for example. It's a "Charisma vs AC" attack. But it says "Melee weapon" in the description.

If I use this power, would I still gain a +2 power bonus to my attack, due to my weapon proficiency?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [this question?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/21518/8610)

Comment: Yes it is! Thanks!